# config.ini not reading string

Tags: python, config, jira

I am trying to build my first `config.ini` file for Python, but having issues using it in my script. I am attempting to use it with the JIRA module for work, so that's where I am hitting a snag. Before using a config file, when assigning a variable, it would look something like this:

```
var1 = issue.fields.customfield10000
```

After trying to get my `config.ini` working, it looks like this:

```py
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

config_data = config['DEV']

var1 = issue.fields.config_data['item']
```

With this, I get the error:

```py
'PropertyHolder' object has no attribute 'config_data'
```

Not really sure where to go from here, hope someone can help, thanks.

I have tried `str(config_data['item']` and `eval(config_data['item']` but both gave me similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

does this help? It worked for me.
Change this:

```
config.read(config.ini)
```

to:

```
config.read("config.ini")
```

Comment: How does your inil file look like?

Comment: Sorry, actually have those added in my script just forgot to type it in here. I edited my post.